# sum 1 column and pick the date on another column

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, casting

I have a table with 2 columns:

```
date | points
```

Data:

```
2015-01-30 00:00:00.000  |    1.2
2015-01-29 00:00:00.000  |    2
2015-01-30 00:00:00.000  |    5
2015-01-27 00:00:00.000  |    7
```

I want to sum `point` column based on `date`. So if I filter date with `2015-01-30 00:00:00.000` then the result would be like the one below:

```
2015-01-30 00:00:00.000  |    7.5
```

The record above is what it should look like.

I have a query but it returns

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

My SQL code.

```
SELECT gpsdate, totkm
FROM (
  SELECT gpsdate,
     cast(cast(cast((SUM(KMRUN)) as float) as int) as nvarchar(50)) as totkm
     ,
     RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY gpsdate 
                 ORDER BY SUM(KMRUN) DESC) as R
 FROM view_tracklist_report
  GROUP BY gpsdate) as InnerQuery
 WHERE InnerQuery.R = 1
```

Comment: what is a type of `points` column? Is it number or varchar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #Test ([date] DATETIME, points FLOAT);

INSERT INTO #Test
    ([date], points)
VALUES
    ('2015-01-30 00:00:00.000', 1.2),
    ('2015-01-29 00:00:00.000', 2),
    ('2015-01-30 00:00:00.000', 5),
    ('2015-01-27 00:00:00.000', 7)
```

Actual Code: Not sure why it should sum to 7.5 tho? 5+1.2=6.2

```
SELECT DISTINCT [date], SUM(points) OVER(PARTITION BY [date]) AS TotPoints
FROM #Test
```

Answer (score 1):

Just group by:

```
Select gpsdate, Sum(CAST(KMRUN AS float)) as KMRUN
From view_tracklist_report
group BY gpsdate
```

Comment: `Error converting data type varchar to float.` it returns this error

Comment: What is the datatype of KMRUN? Check updated statement

Comment: Placing `CAST` in proper place solves the problem. But there is better solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good choice to store numerical values as varchars. If you do so you will have to convert them to numbers in every query. And this is not optimal.

So you have to convert your column tu `FLOAT`. Then you can simply call

```
SUM(KMRUN)
```

without any casting.

Now your `SUM(KMRUN)` is concatenating strings and giving result like

> 1.2257